# Precise syncing in conditional environment

Tags: forward-inverse-search

If I do an inverse search in pdf for a word written within, say `\ifthenelse`, conditional environment, it will take me to the bottom of the `\ifthenelse` block and not at that word in the code `.tex` file.

However, if I do the same for a regular content, my editor TeXShop 3.74 (SyncTeX >=2010) take me exactly at that word. Pl. see the MWE.

```
\documentclass [10pt,letterpaper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newboolean{questions}
\newboolean{solutions}

\begin{document}

\setboolean{questions}{true}
\setboolean{solutions}{false}

 \ifthenelse{\boolean{questions}}{
This is to highlight the issue of syncing when the content is within ``ifthenelse'' case. If I sync in pdf at --- WORD, it will take me to line \#10 and not at WORD.\\

line 2

line3

line4

line5: Even here at --- THIS WORD, it will take me to line \#10. I wish to reach at the exact line/word.\\

line6

line7  

line8

line9

line10\\\\
}{}

Now see here...\\

This content is not within ``ifthenelse'' case. If I sync in pdf at --- WORD, it will take me to WORD and not at line \#10. Is it got to do with Conditional environment?\\

line 2

line3

line4

line5: Here also if I sync --- THIS WORD, it will take me to THIS WORD and not to line \#10. So this is all good.

line6

line7  

line8

line9

line10
\end{document}
```

Comment: Need help on this. May I request you to see attend this? Thank you.

Comment: Request experts to look into this.